# What's are differences between Magento 2 libraries and Magento 2 modules?

Tags: magento2, module, library

The issue is there's no information about this topic in the Magento 2 documentation or anywhere else, so what's a Magento 2 library and what's its main difference compared with a Magento 2 module?

The only thing the Magento 2 documentation says about Magento 2 libraries is that they are installed under the folder `/lib` instead of `/app/code`.

What I have learned by looking at the code in some vendor modules is that Magento 2 libraries use the type `ComponentRegistrar::LIBRARY` in their `registration.php` and that there's no `di.xml` in them but you can still use their classes in the `di.xml` of other modules. See for example `Magento\Framework\MessageQueue` which appears in `/app/etc/di.xml`. Also, since they are not modules, there's no `module.xml` in them.

But that's all. I'm looking for some insight as for when I should use a library instead of a module.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/architecture/archi_perspectives/third-party-libs.html), in my understanding, under /lib should go any library that you can not load through composer.

"There are some required libraries that Composer does not load. These reside in lib/..."